# Can I use a switch statement without break;?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, break

My teacher does not allow us to use things like break, goto, continue...etc
I decided to add a switch statement to my code and I'm stuck because the only way I can make it work is like this:

```
switch (exitValidation)
{
    case 'y':
    case 'Y': exit = false; break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N': Console.WriteLine("\nPlease Enter Valid values");
              exit = false; break;
    default:  exit = true; break;
}
```

Is there a way to use switch without "break;"?
Also, is using "break;" really that bad?

Comment: `break` in `switch` is mandatory. Your teacher probably doesn't like breaking from loops.

Comment: ah that would explain why I couldn't find any other way after searching for almost 1 hour -_-. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @nrodic No, it is not. For more info you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx). It's perfectly acceptable to have one or more cases without a `break` based on the scenarios you want to handle.

Comment: why switch for such a simple thing? use this condition `if(exitValidation.ToLower() == 'y') exit = false` and the same for `n`

Comment: oh I didn't know you could that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In the real world, loop-and-a-half constructs are extremely common when processing input that's terminated with a special value - and having a single exit halfway through the loop using `break` or `return` is (IMO) by far the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A solution is to extract the switch into a method an use its return value:

```
public bool EvaluateSwitch(int exitValidation)
{
    switch (exitValidation)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y': return false;
        case 'n':
        case 'N': Console.WriteLine("\nPlease Enter Valid values");
                  return false;
        default:  return true; 
   }
}
```

Comment: I kept trying to do this earlier but for some reason I keep getting error in "return" even after making it a new method.

Comment: The method needs to specify a `bool` return value, not `void`.

Answer (score 9):

First, your teacher is either misinformed, or you misheard. Using `break` in a `switch` statement is perfectly acceptable and is, in fact, [specified in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/06tc147t.aspx) and will cause a compilation error if it is not present.

You can, however, use `return` from a switch statement to much the same effect. But it will, of course, return the entire method the `switch` is inside.

For example:

```
switch(exitValidation)
{
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        return false;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        return true;
}
```

Comment: I specifically asked him about break; in switch statements and his answer was "there is always a way"

Comment: @BrianNaranjo I guess this is "the way". Still seems like an unnecessary limitation, but if that's what he said...

Comment: @BrianNaranjo also, as someone suggested in another comment, are you sure he doesn't mean you to use an `if` statement?

Answer (score 3):

Just because I hate teachers who restrict usage of correct statements just because they heard that they're "bad", here's a solution without a single break that your teacher will hate, but have to accept:

```
using static System.Console;
var exit = char.ToUpper(exitValidation) switch {
    'Y' => false,
    'N'=> new Func<bool>(() => { WriteLine("\nPlease Enter Valid values"); return false; })(),
    _ => true
};
```